# How does React perform the first render before data is fetched and not cause errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have tried to find and answer but couldn't. I hope someone can clear this up.
How does the DOM render without errors if the data that is passed to components as props isn't fetched yet?
Let's say you want to map the props to a child component. The props don't exist yet. The data to populate the whole downstream of components isn't there.
Shouldn't the first render then cause an error since all logic performs on empty props?

Comment: It might cause an error, or it might not.  It depends on your code.  You should write in in such a way that it doesn't.  For example, show a loading spinner instead of the component for which you don't yet have data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to just return `null` from component, if some data is missing in props.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to pass an id of type string, then you can set an empty string In useState and later update it using setState after fetching the data. Thus there shouldn’t be any error.

Comment: I see. So you would need to "prepopulate"  the data with useState? Isn't that incredibly cumbersome to have state for everything you pass? Is there no other solution?